# internet connected check using NetworkCapabilities

Tags: android, networking, android-networking

I am using this code after checking several posts in stackoverflow.com

It works fine when connected to Cellular and senses whether it is online. However, for Wi-Fi, it gives 'true' always. Observed that c03 and c04 are always true. Is there any way I could check whether device is connected to Internet.

Can some one please help.

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    boolean result = false, c01 = false, c02 = false, c03 = false, c04 = false;

    final ConnectivityManager cM = (ConnectivityManager)context.
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final Network network = cM.getActiveNetwork();
    final NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cM.getNetworkCapabilities(network);

    c01 = cM.getNetworkCapabilities(cM.getActiveNetwork()).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    c02 = cM.getNetworkCapabilities(cM.getActiveNetwork()).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

    c03 = capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    c04 = capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);

    return ((c01 && c03 && c04) || (c02 && c03 && c04));
}
```